# Necesito combinar información de 2 tablas de dstos históricos

Tags: sql-server

Por favor me podrían ayudar con la siguiente consulta.

Tengo 2 Tablas en SQL con la siguiente estructura:

TABLA 1: ITEM FECHA OBSERVACIONES

TABLA 2: ITEM FECHA COMENTARIOS

Necesito juntar las tablas en una sola tabla que me permita organizar la información por mes de la siguiente manera:

TABLA NUEVA:

ITEM FECHA  OBSERVACIONES  COMENTARIOS

Item1 1-abr  OBSERVACIONES COMENTARIOS

Item1 2-abr  OBSERVACIONES COMENTARIOS

Item1 3-abr  OBSERVACIONES COMENTARIOS

Item2 1-abr  OBSERVACIONES COMENTARIOS

Item2 2-abr  OBSERVACIONES COMENTARIOS

Item3 3-abr  OBSERVACIONES COMENTARIOS

.

.

.

.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, deberías de intentar mejorar tú pregunta, con la estructura de las tablas, y el resultado esperado, además de en datos, especificando realmente, lo que significa, *que me permita organizar por mes.*

No obstante, tal cual lo presentas, lo que necesitas es utilizar el operador UNION, que concatena los registros de dos orígenes diferentes.

```
SELECT ITEM, FECHA, OBSERVACIONES AS COMENTARIOS
    FROM TABLA1

UNION ALL

SELECT ITEM, FECHA, COMENTARIOS 
FROM TABLA2
```

Es importante que después de UNION agregues un **ALL** si deseas que no se eliminen los registros duplicados.

Puedes leer un poco más sobre UNION en este artículo.

[Union Vs Union All](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/07/union-vs-union-all/)